# How can we find the value of beta for a transistor to enter in a saturation region?

Tags: transistors

[image: photo of question and schematic]

How can we find the value of beta for a transistor to enter in a saturation region?

For this, the existing value of beta is 50.

Comment: It's a definition. We choose some value and define saturation is the state when the  \$\beta\$ falls below that value. You could choose 20 or 10 or 2, whatever you want. Many vendors seem to choose 10, but there's no reason you couldn't pick some other value.

Comment: In your problem, was the input signal amplitude specified?

Comment: how LOW do you need the Vce to be, once the transistor is saturated?

Comment: No the input signal was not amplitude specific but we have to calculate with the parameters given in the figure and the ans for this question is 116

Comment: And for saturation we need Vbe as 0.2 V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I would answer your question strictly, I would not care about input signal at all.
So you are not looking for working point (what would be practical), but just for value of beta which would take transistor in your circuit into saturation.

When transistor is in saturation Vbe is around 0.7V and Vce around 0.2V. (just ballpark values, these values differ from transistor to transistor).
Then:
\$Ib=(Vcc-Vbe)/Rb=47\mu A\$
\$Ic=(Vcc-Vce)/Rc=5.36 mA\$
\$\beta=Ic/Ib=113.9\$

so the transistor has to have value of beta at least this value

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer